# Understanding the inner workings of Modular Multiplicative Inverse

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, inverse

I'm having a difficult time understanding the Modular Multiplicative Inverse.  I'm new to Python and found an example (below) of finding the Mod Inverse and I'd like a better picture (or understanding) of what's happening here to help me further comprehend this.

Why would finding the **`%`(remainders)** be useful to find the inverse?  After my research, my understanding is finding what I can multiply x by to get (mod m)? (examples below) Why is finding the remainder needed?

I've added a few things below:

> (1) I use [PythonTutor](https://pythontutor.com) (screen shot below) which help me get a visual on what
> exactly is happening step by step.  Any further explanation on what's happening in the IF statement would be helpful.
>
> (2) And a example I jotted down on paper to further show how the
> Inverse is found.   *I'm including this to show
> why I don't understand a remainder is needed.*

**Example:**

```
def modInv(a, m):
     
    for x in range(1, m):
        if (((a%m) * (x%m)) % m == 1):
            return x
    return -1
 

a = 3
m = 11

print(modInv(a, m))

Output: 4
```

In PythonTuter, I see the program going through the range to see if the condition is true/false, if true, return x.   IF Statement finds the remainder of `a%m` and multiplies  it by the remainder of `x%m`. Then use that number to find the remainder of `m`.  Why the need to find all these remainders?

[image]

**Below Image:**
So, for this example `Inverse of 5 mod 7`.  I'm able find the inverse pretty quickly in this problem w/o the need for remainders...

[image]

> Ultimately, I'm really trying to wrap around why remainders are
> needed in a function above to find the inverse.  Any help understanding
> this would be appreciated.

Comment: Your pen-and-paper way is just a different algorithm. The Python code you showed just tries each possible number and checks whether it is the inverse. Your pen-and-paper solution does something different which you could also implement in Python if you wanted to.

Comment: Maybe this can help -https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/module-inverse.html

Comment: I suggest you try asking on [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Note that `5 % 7` is equal to `5`. So the example with a=5 and m=7 won't help you understand why replacing `a` by `a % m` can be useful.